# drop columns if specific row contains given value

Tags: r

I would like to drop columns if their fourth row contains "0"

dummy dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), b=(c(0,1,2,0,3,4)), c=c(1,2,0,4,5,6), d=c(1,7,9,4,5,6))
```

I've already used this to remove columns when any rows was containing a zero value :

```
b <- df[,-grep("0", df)]
```

but I can't find a way to do it with a specific row...

Any ideas ?

Comment: `df[, -grep("0", df[4,])]` ? Better to use `!grepl` instead of `-grep` though, so you won't get an error in case there are no zeroes at all in 4th row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly simple solution.

```
df[,which(df[4,]!=0)]
```

Comment: Damn I tried this but I forgot to add the comma after the 4 !
Many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
subset(df, select=which(df[4,]!=0))
```